# Digitized contours on map and interpolate contour line to create surface

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I have digitized the contours on a map and I want to recreate the surface by interpolating (using IDW) using these contour line. When I generate contours (extract) to see how well they match with the input parameters (digitized contours they are quite off.  I set the interpolation for IDW with a P of 20, if I use 2 then bulls eyes form on the raster.
I am not sure if I am using the right approach. should convert the lines to points? Use a different interpolation method etc?

Comment: This might help you https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM.

Comment: If you're interested in trying GRASS GIS, there a module `r.surf.contours` that interpolates a DEM from contour lines:  [here](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.surf.contour.html)

Answer (score -1):

I finally used RST interpolation which gave comparable contours as the original map.